# my flutter project did not open in iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

when I tried open flutter project from android studio in Xcode iOS Simulator

flutter output:
2021-02-26 16:53:42.961 xcodebuild[3871:51012] warning:  The file reference for        "Firebase.debug.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files");   this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2021-02-26 16:53:42.961 xcodebuild[3871:51012] warning:  The file reference for "Firebase.release.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2021-02-26 16:53:42.969 xcodebuild[3871:51012] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleUtilities.debug.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
2021-02-26 16:53:42.969 xcodebuild[3871:51012] warning:  The file reference for "GoogleUtilities.release.xcconfig" is a member of multiple groups ("Support Files" and "Support Files"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
** BUILD FAILED **

```
Xcode's output:
 ↳
/Users/raghad/StudioProjects/GP_Last_Edition/ios/Pods/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics/Firebase/CoreDiagnostics/FIRCDLibrary/FIRCoreDiagnostics.m:22:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found
#import <GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/raghad/StudioProjects/GP_Last_Edition/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRLogger.m:17:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found
#import <GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/raghad/StudioProjects/GP_Last_Edition/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRHeartbeatInfo.m:16:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULHeartbeatDateStorage.h' file not found
#import <GoogleUtilities/GULHeartbeatDateStorage.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
/Users/raghad/StudioProjects/GP_Last_Edition/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRFirebaseUserAgent.m:19:9: fatal error: 'GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h' file not found
#import <GoogleUtilities/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'fluttertoast' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleIPhoneUtilities' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleInterchangeUtilities' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleSymbolUtilities' from project 'Pods')
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstanceID' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseMessaging' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

I found in this website solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66730

but when I tried open my project in Xcode it show me

Could not open file. (/Users/raghad/StudioProjects/GP_Last_Edition)

flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale en-SA)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
   flutter:
   sdk: flutter
  

   cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
   carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
   http: ^0.12.2
   firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
   firebase_auth: "^0.20.0+1"
   firebase_database: "^6.0.0"
   fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
   firebase_messaging:





   # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.


dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter
   #integration_test:
   #   sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
  flutter:

# The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
# included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
# the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

# To add assets to your appl
```

Comment: Try to close xcode and run `pod install` ios directory

Comment: I did it output is:Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

Comment: but the same error appear to me

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

```dart
The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99.
```

You need to change in your podfile.lock the iOS version to which you are constructing the app (between 9.0 and 14.4.99).

In podfile you will change the parameter `platform` and `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`] (If you have it)

After this you should change the version in Xcode (Runner tab), clean and build again..

Comment: how I can change the version in Xcode (Runner tab) in Xcode, please explain?

Comment: Click in Runner and then choose the version in both runners (project and target) https://imgur.com/1diMDdi